# How do you create a view that removes fields in mongoose?

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose

Looking at the documentation there is a way to modify the fields:

```
await RedactedUser.createCollection({
  viewOn: 'users', // Set `viewOn` to the collection name, **not** model name.
  pipeline: [
    {
      $set: {
        name: { $concat: [{ $substr: ['$name', 0, 3] }, '...'] },
        email: { $concat: [{ $substr: ['$email', 0, 3] }, '...'] }
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

But is there a way to remove the "name" and "email" fields? Using `$unset` throws an error saying it's not valid.

Comment: Using $unset where and how? What specific error message?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I just needed to update to mongodb to 4.X, this caused the error to go away when using `$unset`

Comment: Excellent! Upgrading was a good thing to do anyway, but for what it's worth [$unset is an alias for $project](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unset/#-unset-and--project). So you probably could have done the same in 4.0 via $project instead

Comment: Yea I was using mongo 3.6, so I needed to upgrade to 4.X, $unset works like a charm now! Thanks a lot!